# Why my AngularJS directive don't work in Edge?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, microsoft-edge, jquery-ui-slider

This code work fine in all major browsers, but Edge show valid value only in DOM inspector, but at the page still old value. Why?

```
(function (angular, module) {

  'use strict';

  module
    .directive('psEffectsDurationSlider', EffectsDurationSlider);

  EffectsDurationSlider.$inject = [];

  function EffectsDurationSlider() {
    return {
      require:  'ngModel',
      restrict: 'E',
      link:     link
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$render = render;

      activate();

      function initializeSlider() {
        element.slider({
          min:         0.2,
          max:         2,
          step:        0.1,
          animate:     true,
          orientation: 'horizontal',
          range:       'min',
          slide:       onSliderChange
        });
      }

      function render() {
        element.slider('value', ngModel.$viewValue);
      }

      function onSliderChange(event, ui) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ui.value);
      }

      function onScopeDestroy() {
        element.slider('destroy');
      }

      function activate() {
        initializeSlider();

        scope.$on('$destroy', onScopeDestroy);
      }
    }
  }

})(window.angular, window.angular.module('...'));
```

Screenshot from Edge with valid value in the DOM inspector and invalid result at the page:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the model update in `$timeout` since the slider event is outside of angular context

```
 function onSliderChange(event, ui) {
    $timeout(function(){
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ui.value);
    });
  }
```

Will also need to inject `$timeout`